# Returning a blob via Meteor always results in empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, request, blob

So the below code is the body of a function on the server-side, which I'm later consuming on the client side of the same app:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function fetchImage(url) {
  // url: image file url like: http://example.com/img1.png
  const res = await fetch(url);

  const blob = await res.blob();

  console.log(blob);
  /* logs a blob successfully 
  Blob {
  I20200316-01:00:19.551(2)?   [Symbol(type)]: 'image/jpeg',
  I20200316-01:00:19.551(2)?   [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 
  4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff e1 0e d2 45 78 69 66 00 00 
  4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 0c 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 03 e8 ... 133125 
  more bytes>
  */

  return blob;
  // this however will ALWAYS return {} empty object
}
```

I tried doing something like `return 'Hello Bros!'` just for my sanity and it gets consumed properly.

It's just the blob will not return no matter what.

**I'm basically trying to proxy a call on the server side to fetch some images that I can display in the browser.**

The caller function

```js
async function getImageBlob(url) {
    const res = await fetchImage(url);
    console.log(res, 'response which is always {} instead of my precious blob');
  }
```

**The full longer version**

**server**

```js
Meteor.methods({
  async 'products.fetchImage'(url) {
    check(url, String);

    const res = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await res.blob();
    console.log(blob, '!!!server blob!!!'); // logs just fine
    return blob;
  }
})
```

**client**

```js
// image uploader
import vueFilePond, { setOptions } from 'vue-filepond';

setOptions({
  server: {
    // initialize image uploader with images already stored on the server
    load: async (source, load) => {
      // source: 'http://example.com/img1.png'
      const response = await meteorCall('products.fetchImage', source);
      console.log('blob?', response); // logs {}
      load(response);
    },
  },
});
const FilePond = vueFilePond();
```

Comment: I'd say this entirely depends on what you're doing with the return value. Please show the code that uses this async function

Comment: @Phil updated my question with more details.

Comment: Is `callMyBackend` the name of the function at the top of your question? Could you please flesh out your post so it contains a [minimal, **complete**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Phil yes it's the same function, updated.

Comment: The only logical explanation here is that the caller of `fetchImage()` is not treating the return value as a promise.  Show us the REAL code for the caller of `fetchImage()` and we can likely spot your problem.  The `getImageBlob()` function you show will work just fine as you show it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you should be using `console.log` like that. Typically, when using multiple arguments, the first is some sort of label. How about `console.log('this should be a blob', res)`?

Comment: @Phil - You can send arguments to `console.log()` in any order you want.  It just renders then in the order you send them.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, kinda clutching at straws now. I guess I just wanted to make sure OP wasn't accidentally concatenating the blob as a string

Comment: I have updated the post with more details, I was afraid I might confuse people with the unnecessary wrappers around this. Sorry.

Comment: The issue is probably with `meteorCall`. If I understand correctly, that function actually does an RPC on the server. In that case, it could be that whatever serializes the result back to the browser doesn't know how to serialize a blob and just returns an empty object (`JSON.stringify` maybe?). You'll want to investigate how that can be handled with the framework you're using.

Comment: From the server method, try returning `await blob.arrayBuffer()`. MeteorJS' documentation mentions that their [EJSON format supports binaries](https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html), so see if it recognizes the `ArrayBuffer` class instead of node-fetch's blob.

Comment: @cubrr awesome there's something now!
The client now reads response as `Uint8Array` but it has everything inside it set to `0`, like `byteLength` and `length`.

Comment: If you are really out for sending this as a blob you may use Meteor's built-in `WebApp` to send it via standard http request instead of websocket. Otherwise I think you will be better supported with `Buffer` than with Blob.

Comment: @Jankapunkt
I checked the documentation for `WebApp` and I tried using it but it always throws a Reference error that it's no defined in the first place.

There's no mention on how to import it, I'm unsure where it's located. I'm still blocked after more than a week :(